# How can I get the information I have saved in a structure inside a binary file by means of c?

Tags: c

I have to make a fixed-size file which I define with a character-filled char array [1024] so each position has the character '\ 0' and thus I can define the size but inside this I have two structures one at the beginning And another one in the middle of it, when I read the one that at the beginning managed to recover the information but the one in the middle I position myself with fseek where I have written it and what I find is only the 0's with which to fill in .. 
Here is the code

> ```
>       Ext extend;
>       extend.part_status=0;
>       strcpy(extend.part_name,"prueba 2.0");
>       extend.part_start=x;
>
>       FILE *texto;
>       texto=fopen(leer_arch,"w+b");
>       if(texto){
>
>           fwrite(&mbr_init, sizeof(Disco),1,texto);
>
>       fseek(texto,sizeof(mbr_init) ,SEEK_SET);
>       int nuevotam=(x-sizeof(mbr_init))/1024;
>       int i;
>       for(i=0;i<nuevotam;i++){
>
>           fwrite(&relleno,sizeof(relleno),1,texto);
>       }
>
>       fseek(texto,x,SEEK_SET);
>       fwrite(&extend, sizeof(Ext),1,texto);
>
>
>       int tamanito=x+extend.part_size;
>       nuevotam=(tam-tamanito)/1024;
>
>       for(i=0;i<nuevotam  ;i++){
>           fwrite(&relleno,sizeof(relleno),1,texto);
>       }
>       fclose(texto);
>       FILE *texto2;
>       Ext prueb;
>       texto2=fopen(leer_arch,"w+b");
>       if(texto2){
>       fseek(texto2,x,SEEK_SET);
>       int prueba = fread(&prueb, sizeof(Ext),1,texto2);
>       printf(prueb.part_name);
>
>       }
> ```

I think my problem is when I position myself but it is exactly the same number that I use when I write the one I use to read it

Comment: MCVE, please...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but it is more urgent that you read about how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea. It is not clear from your description what you mean about the three structures. You've not shown us those structures. You've not demonstrated valid input and expected vs actual output. That all makes it hard to help you — hence we need an MCVE.